# Are overridden functions/method still accessible?

Tags: javascript, overloading

I'm thinking about ways of managing the behaviour of JavaScript on the client.

Suppose at the top of my HTML page, I have...

```
<script>

var XMLHttpRequest = function () {
   this.send = function() {
     alert(args.toString());
   }

};
```

Is it subsequently possible (on the same page) to access the native `XMLHttpRequest` object?

(obviously, from a security viewpoint this is not the best way to prevent XSS - that's not the question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `XMLHttpRequest` is a property of the `window` object, you should still be able to access it through that.

You have not actually overwritten it, you have only shadowed the native property of `window` so any time you try to call `XMLHttpRequest` in the scope of your declaration, your overridden version will be encountered first in the scope chain and therefore executed. If you explicity access `window.XMLHttpRequest` you will bypass your overridden version and access the native one directly:

```
var XMLHttpRequest = function() {
   console.log('example');
}
var request = new XMLHttpRequest(); //Calls the above function
var request2 = new window.XMLHttpRequest(); //Calls the native function
```

Note that if you had not declared your version with the `var` keyword, you would actually have overridden the native function, and in that case you can get it back (but not in Internet Explorer) by deleting the new property:

```
delete window.XMLHttpRequest;
```

**Edit**

I just realised the above is slightly misleading. If you omit the `var` keyword, you don't actually overwrite the original function, you are still just shadowing it. That is because the original function is declared on the prototype of the `window` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

In FF12 that's a perfectly valid override. The XMLHttpRequest will not be available anymore afterwards.

Bear in mind other browsers use other methods which may not be accessible in that way; I haven't tested those.

Edit: Tested in IE9 as well, the XHR didn't work anymore there too.